# Microsoft bing maps api and loading modules issue

Tags: promise, bluebird

I'm building a store locator and loading a custom module via require. The custom module is dependent on Directions & Search module from microsoft. I hate the callback hell and want to pre load the modules return a promise and action on the custom module once everything is loaded.

Using bluebird for Promise spec and I've tried several approaches `Promise.method`, `Promise.promisify`, `new Promise(function(resolve, reject){Microsoft.Maps.loadModule({callback:resolve})})` I can't seem to get any of them working.

My latest implementation:

```
function loadSearch() {
            var resolver = Promise.defer();
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', {
                callback: resolver.resolve
            });
            return resolver.promise;
        } /* end loadSearch */ 

        function loadDirections() {
            var resolver = Promise.defer();
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', {
                callback: resolver.resolve
            });
            return resolver.promise;
        }

Promise.all([loadSearch(), loadDirections()], function() {
        //do something
    });
```

results in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_tryFollow' of undefined bluebird.js`
Can anyone point out what an obvious error in the latest code or a psuedo code example of loading modules in a promise fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, first of all, `Promise.all` in Bluebird does not accept a second argument like that, it returns a promise, try :

```
Promise.all([loadSearch(), loadDirections()]).then(function(results) {
    //do something
});
```

Or better

```
Promise.all([loadSearch(), loadDirections()]).spread(function(search,dirs) {
    //do something
});
```

Second of all, the methods of defer are not bound to the defer instance (JS has dynamic this), use the promise constructor instead:

```
function loadDirections() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', {
             callback: resolve // since this is not a method this is not bound
        });
    });
}
```

And so on. generally, it is better to prefer the promise constructor over the deferred interface in Bluebird.

In total:

```
function loadSearch() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', {
            callback: resolve
        });
    });
} 
function loadDirections() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', {
            callback: resolve
        });
    });
}
Promise.all([loadDirections(),loadSearch()]).spread(function(dir,search){
     //both done, results here
});
```

For what it's worth - I've just raised the issue and better error messages will be given in future versions of Bluebird.

Comment: @Esailija whoops :D Thanks fore the catch.

Comment: Bluebird will now provide better error messages in this case https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/commit/d8014cdef319da01a6bd0a076b5ab6f4b39ed3cc

Comment: Ah missed the '.then()' in api docs, but I'm confused about promise.defer() vs the constructor. 
The api [docs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#callback---function) for `.callback` are an exact example of using deferred as I have and even make a comment about
"This is more efficient way of promisification than using `new Promise.`"
---
On another note can you explain here or in a pm `Promise.promisify`. I felt like I should be able to do something like `var promiseLM = Promise.promisifyAll(Microsoft.Maps.loadModule)` and used it something like `promiseLM().then()`

Comment: Promise.promisify and promisifyAll are for nodebacks - a way of writing callbacks that Microsoft.Maps doesn't do (at leasft from what I can tell here). You can learn more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises