# How to combine multiple callbacks? Specifically for BingMap module loading

Tags: javascript, callback, bing-maps

I have the following code that I am looking to simplify:

```
var MM = Microsoft.Maps;
MM.loadModule("MM.Clustering", function () { 
    MM.loadModule("HtmlPushpinLayerModule", function () { 
        // Do actual work
    });
});
```

Is it possible to combine these into something like (pseudocode):

```
MM.loadModule("MM.Clustering") && MM.loadModule("HtmlPushpinLayerModule"), function() {
    // Do actual work
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and use [Promise#all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)  for waiting for the callbacks.

You can see something like this in this question:
[Microsoft bing maps api and loading modules issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227346/microsoft-bing-maps-api-and-loading-modules-issue)

Comment: Unfortunately can't use this approach for Internet Explorer 11, since it doesn't support promises.

Comment: You can use some polyfill for IE 11 to make compatible with most recent browsers.